# Deploying ASP.NET Core Web API with SQL database

Tags: asp.net, database, azure, asp.net-core, deployment

I have created a small todo app for my resume. Now I am struggling with deploying (backend: ASP.NET Core Web API, frontend: vueJs and database).

I have tried to deploy the ASP.NET Core Web API to Azure, but failed to connect with the database.

Could you explain the full deployment process?

Comment: Where does your database belongs to? `Azure` as well? If so replace your connection string before publishing your app to `azure portal` then, you should have `resource group` under that `resource group` you should have the `app service`. You have to finally publish your app on this `app service` then your application can operational. If you have your `backend` and `frontend` in different project then do the same. If your application has `authentication` stuff integrated then you have to have a look on `azure active directory` as well.

Comment: No, My database is on my local machine. I have tried to deploy it on azure but failed.

Comment: Does it mean that your deployment was successful but you cannot connect the database right? If so then you cannot connect your local database with deployed app unless you have hybrid connection with `azure SQL` to your `local database`. You can have a look on our [official guideline here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/using-azure-app-services-with-hybrid-connections/)

Comment: Well, I found what is wrong. It is connection between azure SQL server and my app. I configured everything shown in doc but database responds 400 status

Answer (score 1):

You just need to configure it under App Settings -> Configuration

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-connection-strings